# Can Minecraft Bedrock addons be used in Minecraft Education Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition, minecraft-addons

I am playing Minecraft Education Edition and I want to play with addons. The way you get addons is similar to Bedrock but with one main difference: there is no experimental gameplay. Can you still play some Bedrock addons? I am playing on 1.17.31.2.

Comment: How are you trying to get these addons

Answer (score -1):

You can upload mods from Tynker.com, but you have to create them. I play Education and I haven't found any sites that can upload to Education.

Edit
No sites besides Tynker.